# How to customize the temporary directory in Twisted Trial

Tags: testing, integration-testing, twisted

I am trying to run a twisted.trial.TestCase that depends on resource folders (images, for instance) that reside alongside my Python package called `test`. Unfortunately, the temporary directory that gets created upon running the test runner (i.e. issuing `trial test`) doesn't include (naturally) a copy of the whole original working directory, and my tests fail because the images cannot be found. The function of the software is heavily dependent on those images, so they'll need to be a part of testing.

The question is, is there a way to customize the `_trial_temp` directory that the test runner normally creates from scratch so that it includes certain files and folders, besides what the test runner itself thinks it needs?

Comment: If you have resources, such as images, css files, javascript modules, etc, then use Glyph's answer.  But if you simply have modules that you need to access located in another directory, you can simply set your environment's Python Path:  ``export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/module.py``

Not really an answer to your question, but it may help someone who stumbles upon this question.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Don't do it this way.  If you need data from your project, it is not in any sense *temporary* data.  If you point trial at a directory using `--temp-directory`, it will assume it is in fact "temporary" and will blow it away.  Instead, you should access the data relative to the path of the tests.

If you put your sample data into the same directory as your tests, and treat it as `package_data`, you can do this:

```
from twisted.python.modules import getModule
thisModule = getModule(__name__)
dataPath = thisModule.filePath.parent()
```

and to get data in your tests:

```
fileobj = dataPath.child("sample_file.data").open()
databytes = dataPath.child("other_file.txt").getContent()
```

so keep your temporary directories and your sample data separate.